# changing size of active navbar item in bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Below example show a navbar in bootstrap 3.

```
<div class="navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse collapse" style="height: 1px;">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a href="index.html">Item 1</a></li>
                            <li class="active"><a href="about.html">Item 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="blog.html">Item 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="contact.html">Item 4</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

The output of code show below.
I want show a line below active item instead of blueviolent box that show around activity item.

[image]

How can I do it?!

Answer (score 0):

Try going to your CSS and adding:

```
.navbar-nav li.active {
   background-color: none;
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Or maybe this

```
.navbar-nav > .active > a {
   background-color: none;
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```